# How to set where the text cursor is in TWTweetComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, cursor

I am using the TWTweetComposeViewController, and when I set the initial text to the title of the screen, the text cursor appears after the hashtag, and I want to have it appear before the hashtag. Is there a way to do something like cursor=(0,0) or something like that? I looked in the documentation and there's nothing there.

For reference, this is what I'm using.

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc]init];
[tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", self.title]];
tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
};
[self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked for the exact same thing. It can be done with a little hack. This is the source http://www.sunetos.com/items/2012/06/04/cleanly-accessing-the-uitextview-field-in-twtweetcomposeviewcontroller-2/

According to the author the app was approved for the app store.

```
// at an appropriate place in your code, 
// add and remove the observer for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleKeyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];

- (UIView *) findFirstResponderInView:(UIView*) view
{
    if (view.isFirstResponder) {
        return view;
    }
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        UIView *result = [self findFirstResponderInView:subview];
        if (result) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void) handleKeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) notification;
{
    UIView *fr = [self findFirstResponder:self.tweetSheetViewController.view];
    if ([fr isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        UITextView *tv = (UITextView *) fr;
        [tv setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0,0)];
    }
}
```

Did implement it like this in my app, so if you need further help let me know.